# Azure Devops Release Pipeline - Matching Branch Gate

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'd like to set up a pre-deployment gate with the following logic

- If the branch (embedded in the artifact names, i.e. 1.2.4-myBranch)
  matches the currently deployed branch (to the stage in question) allow the release to deploy automatically
- If it doesn't match, require a manual override before the release is
  deployed

The reason for this is we have multiple test environments where generally we only want to allow a release from the same branch to overwrite the deployment but obviously once we're done with a particular phase of testing we'd want to change the deployed branch.

I can't see any obvious way to do this, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround:

We could create two Stages A and B

Select the stage A and configure the pre-deployment as below:

[image]

And configure stage B trigger mode to Manual only

[image]

Result:

If the branch match master, it will allow the release stage A to deploy automatically.

If not, we need to manually deploy stage B

[image]

[image]

You could also add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?from=email&space=21&entry=suggestion), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.